# How can I go to the next week using nscalendar & nsdate when an button is pressed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nscalendar

When my tableview loads it grabs data from a mysql database based on the current week we are in.  This all works fine but I also want the user to be able to click a UIButton that loads data for the next week.  After that the button stays there and can be clicked over and over to go to the following weeks.

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
    NSCalendar *cal =[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    [cal setFirstWeekday:3]; //


    NSDate *beginningOfWeek = nil;
    [cal rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit startDate:&beginningOfWeek interval:nil forDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *beginComponents = [cal components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:beginningOfWeek];

    NSDateComponents *offset = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [offset setDay:6];
    [offset setHour:23];
    NSDate *endOfWeek = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:beginningOfWeek options:0];
    NSDateComponents *endComponents = [cal components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:endOfWeek];

    NSTimeInterval tiStart = [beginningOfWeek timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval tiEnd = [endOfWeek timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *startWeekString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tiStart];
    NSString *endWeekString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tiEnd];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/test.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:startWeekString forKey:@"startweek"];
    [request setPostValue:endWeekString forKey:@"endweek"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}

-(IBAction)nextWeek:(id)sender {

}
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor all of your calendar and date component code into a method that takes as an argument an NSDate (starting date) and &startWeekString and &endWeekString, and populates those latter two values.
Track the current week (or currently used starting date) in a variable, and inside of nextWeek, increment that variable by a week, and pass it to your calendar method.